# How to write streaming data on console with specific chunk of size/records?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I need to read a CSV file through spark streaming and write the output stream to console with specific chunk of rows/size.

Used spark streaming `readStream` to read CSV and `writeStream` to write it in console.

```
val df: DataFrame = sparkSession.readStream
      .option("sep", ",")
      .schema(userSchema)
      .csv("path")


val res: StreamingQuery = df.writeStream
      .format("console")
      .start()
```

I expect all 50000 rows to be displayed in console in chunks of 50 rows, but I am getting only 20 rows or I need to set a number to be display in console.

Answer (score 5):

You can set number to rows to display by setting '**numRows**' property on writestream.

```
 df.writeStream
 .option("numRows",50)
```

Comment: Yes, it will show only the specified rows, but i need to show all rows in csv file as 50 rows per chunk. As of now am getting only one set of output show in console.